# How the changing the app Display Name is affect the app status

Tags: facebook, status

My app is submitted and has 'live & listed' status. 
So, if i change the Display Name field - will this affect the app status and App Center listing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once you have submitted your app detail page, the values cannot be changed until your app is listed or you cancel the submission. Once your app detail page is listed in the App Center, all future changes to the page will also be subject to review.

For more details: [App Center Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter/)

Comment: ok, what about the time the app in review again?   
will it be available at App Center that time or not?